# Some times I am getting typing activity in chatbot V4 template. With out selecting/typing any text

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-storage-emulator

Typing activity Issue in chatbot v4 Template.

I tried with Middle ware and Activity Types still I am facing issue.

Step 1:

```
var typingMiddleware = new ShowTypingMiddleware();
options.Middleware.Add(typingMiddleware)
```

Step 2:

```
options.Middleware.Add(new ShowTypingMiddleware(delay:500,period:2000));
```

Step 3:

```
var typingMsg = dc.Context.Activity.CreateReply();

typingMsg.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;

await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(typingMsg);
```

Step 4:

```
var typingActivity = new Activity
                    {
                        Type = ActivityTypes.Typing,
                        RelatesTo = turnContext.Activity.RelatesTo,
                    };

var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
typingActivity.ApplyConversationReference(conversationReference);
await turnContext.Adapter.SendActivitiesAsync(turnContext, new Activity[] { typingActivity }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Typing activity should display for 2-4 sec after that It should not display that typing activity bubble in chatbot.

Comment: Can you please list the version of the nuget Botbuilder package(s) you are using?